# How do I properly implement collision response in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm trying to program a simple top-down dungeon crawler in Pygame and I've already hit a roadblock in designing my collision response. So far I've programmed player movement, collision detection (only knows when a player hits a wall) and player-to-mouse rotation, the latter of which is disabled to simplify this solution.

I've tried the normal method of moving the character, checking for collision, changing the character's position if needed and then drawing all elements to the screen.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import sys
import math

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('sourcecodeproblack', 12)

BLACK = [0, 0, 0]
WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
WALLS = [220, 40, 30]

SIZE = [240, 240]
DSIZE = [480, 480]
TSIZE = [720, 720]

dub = False
trip = False

def normal():
    global screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("METAL PACKET")

def full():
    global screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SIZE), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    pygame.display.set_caption("METAL PACKET: Fullscreen Edition")

def doubled():
    global screen
    global window
    global res
    global invscale
    invscale = 1/2
    res = DSIZE
    window = pygame.display.set_mode(DSIZE)
    screen = pygame.Surface(SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("METAL PACKET: Double Boogaloo")

def doubledfull():
    global screen
    global window
    global res
    global invscale
    invscale = 1/2
    res = DSIZE
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((DSIZE), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    screen = pygame.Surface(SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("METAL PACKET: Fullscreen Boogaloo")

def tripled ():
    global screen
    global window
    global res
    global invscale
    invscale = 1/3
    res = TSIZE
    window = pygame.display.set_mode(TSIZE)
    screen = pygame.Surface(SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("METAL PACKET: Trifecta of Resolution")

def tripledfull ():
    global screen
    global window
    global res
    global invscale
    invscale = 1/3
    res = TSIZE
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((TSIZE), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    screen = pygame.Surface(SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("METAL PACKET: Fullscreen Trifecta Edition")

print("")
print("1: 240 x 240")
print("2: 480 x 480")
print("3: 720 x 720")
print("4: 240 x 240 Fullscreen")
print("5: 480 x 480 Fullscreen")
print("6: 720 x 720 Fullscreen")
print("")
res = input("Choose a video mode. ")
if res == ("1"):
    normal()
if res == ("2"):
    doubled()
    dub = True
if res == ("3"):
    tripled()
    trip = True
if res == ("4"):
    full()
if res == ("5"):
    doubledfull()
    dub = True
if res == ("6"):
    tripledfull()
    trip = True

class Walls(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.currentsprite = ()
    def draw(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.currentsprite)
        screen.blit(self.image, [0, 0])

room1 = Walls()
room1.currentsprite = ("room1.png")

collidelist = pygame.sprite.Group()

class WallColliders(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, collidelist)
        self.rectval = []
    def collide(self):
        self.rect = (self.rectval)

topwall = WallColliders()
topwall.rectval = [0, 0, 240, 20]
bottomwall = WallColliders()
bottomwall.rectval = [0, 160, 240, 20]
leftwall = WallColliders()
leftwall.rectval = [0, 0, 20, 180]

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.collide = 0
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.speed = 0
        self.currentsprite = ("pac.png")
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.currentsprite)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def collidedetect(self):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, collidelist):
            self.collide = 1
        else:
            self.collide = 0
    def move(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[K_LEFT] or key[ord("a")]:
                self.x -= self.speed
                if self.collide == 1:
                    self.x += self.speed
                    self.collide = 0
        if key[K_RIGHT] or key[ord("d")]:
                self.x += self.speed
                if self.collide == 1:
                    self.x -= self.speed
                    self.collide = 0
        if key[K_UP] or key[ord("w")]:
                self.y -= self.speed
                if self.collide == 1:
                    self.y += self.speed
                    self.collide = 0
        if key[K_DOWN] or key[ord("s")]:
                self.y += self.speed
                if self.collide == 1:
                    self.y -= self.speed
                    self.collide = 0
        if self.collide == 1:
            print("collide")
    def rotate(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if dub == True or trip == True:
            pos = pos[0] * invscale, pos[1] * invscale
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pos
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pos
        rel_x, rel_y = mouse_x - self.x, mouse_y - self.y
        self.angle = (180 / math.pi) * -math.atan2(rel_y, rel_x) 
        self.rotimage = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, self.angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.rotimage.get_rect(center=(self.rect.center))
    def monitor(self):
        textsurface = myfont.render(str(self.angle), False, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(textsurface,(50,210))
    def draw(self):
        #screen.blit(self.rotimage, [self.x, self.y])
        screen.blit(self.image, [self.x, self.y])
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 20, 20)

player = Player()
player.x = 29
player.y = 89
player.speed = 3

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            print("")
            print("See you next time.")
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
            done = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    room1.draw()

    for x in collidelist:
        x.collide()

    player.collidedetect()
    player.move()
    #player.rotate()
    #player.monitor()
    player.draw()

    if dub == True or trip == True:        
        pygame.transform.scale(screen, res, window)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

For some reason this will stick the player in the wall unless they press move diagonally instead of moving the player out of the wall and resetting collision. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could read through my code and suggest any improvement, optimisation or solution. Any example code would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Hello ! Your example is quite long. Giving a minimal working example will help you receive valuable answer. Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: It's plenty of pygame collision examples on stack overflow. Did you try reading those questions and see if they are helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate. When the player is moved, the calculate the new position and update the `.rect` property of the `Player` object:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def move(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[K_LEFT] or key[ord("a")]:
                self.x -= self.speed
        if key[K_RIGHT] or key[ord("d")]:
                self.x += self.speed
        if key[K_UP] or key[ord("w")]:
                self.y -= self.speed
        if key[K_DOWN] or key[ord("s")]:
                self.y += self.speed
        self.updaterect()

    def updaterect(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 20, 20)
```

In the main loop:

- backup the player position
- move the player
- check for collision
- if there is a collision, then restore the position of the player

```py
while not done:

    # [...]

    pos = (player.x, player.y)
    player.move()
    player.collidedetect()
    if player.collide:
        player.x, player.y = pos
        player.updaterect()
        player.collide = False

    player.draw()

    # [...]
```

---

Of course this can be done in a method, too:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def moveandcollide(self):
        pos = (self.x, self.y)
        self.move()
        self.collidedetect()
        if player.collide:
            self.x, self.y = pos
            self.updaterect()
            self.collide = False
```

```py
while not done:

    # [...]

    player.moveandcollide()
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it solved my code immediately! I've used the definition method and the player now collides and can slide along any wall. I re-enabled rotation and it still works perfectly.